# RegEx Find all xml attribute value

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract all attribute values from a large xml file

```
s = '<some id="Foo" menu="BAAR"></some>'
output = re.findall( '="(.*)"' ,s)
print output
```

I'm expecting out put

```
['Foo','BAAR']
```

However I'm getting

```
['Foo" menu="BAAR']
```

Can anyone please help me pointing out what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: don't use regular expressions to parse XML!

Comment: You might find useful using xpath for this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In regular expression `*` is greedy, that means, it takes as much as it can. Just use the non-greedy version `*?`:

```
s = '<some id="Foo" menu="BAAR"></some>'
output = re.findall( '="(.*?)"' ,s)
print output
```